# I have a 10 page pdf. How can can I use this as a background for a new document?

Tags: pdftex, backgrounds, wallpaper

I have a 10 page pdf. I want to use latex to add some text and equations to each page of this pdf. How can this be achieved?

Here's how I do it right now:

1. Split the 10 page file into ten single page pdfs.
2. Call each page from latex using a function from the `wallpaper` package.

I want to find a better way of doing this.

Here is some minimal code showing my current method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\begin{document}

\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{page1.pdf}
The total charge distribution is the sum of all the volume elements.
\pagebreak

\ThisULCornerWallPaper{1}{page2.pdf}
This is some random text for the second page.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will copy the document and allow you to overlap text.  You might have difficulty matching the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{coffeestains}% MWE only, takes two runs

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight)
  {\includegraphics[page=\value{page}]{../acoustic/enclosure}}}% any document will do
  
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\coffeestainA{0.5}{1.0}{0}{0pt}{0pt}
\newpage
\coffeestainB{0.5}{1.0}{0}{0pt}{0pt}
\newpage
\coffeestainC{0.5}{1.0}{0}{0pt}{0pt}
\newpage
\coffeestainD{0.1}{1.0}{0}{0pt}{0pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool package. Is there a \coffeestainE  command? How about for pdf's longer than 26 pages?

Comment: Alas, only A through D (see manual).  Some blank paper, a scanner and tikzpagenodes and you can create as many as you like.

Comment: This answer is fantastic. The package and preamble does the job, and there is an option to add coffee stains as well.